# How do I obtain the offical Ubuntu patched kernel source without using git?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, compiling

I'm needing to custom compile a kernel to enable some very specific hardware features that are not on by default and have to be compiled in.  I started following this guide but it seems to be slightly outdated for 12.04 onwards as some commands fail with missing source packages.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

What is the easiest way to rebuild the current kernel source so I can tweak the options I need?

Answer (score 3):

These steps are *very general* and apply to every package in Ubuntu/Debian.

1. This will download the source package and applies all Ubuntu patches.

   ```
   apt-get source linux-image-3.... # select the exact package you want
   ```
2. Install all build dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-3...
   ```
3. Enter the directory of the source.

   ```
   cd linux-... # change accordingly
   ```
4. Do the changes to the source you need.
5. After finishing the edits, add a new version to the changelog (else it's going to complain the source doesn't match):

   ```
   dch --local mysuffix
   ```
6. Build it with unsigned changes file and unsigned source package (for local testing):

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   This will take a while!
7. Find the packages one level below:

   ```
   ls -al ../*.deb
   ```
8. Install them like any other package.